# I don't understand what this sentence means

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns, compound-sentences

> Investors are grateful that the attorney general has stepped in to pursue inquiries into the misfeasance in the financial markets, given that the regulators officially charged with policing the industry have been diffident.

Even if I looked up for each new word I met, this sentence still doesn't make sense to me. You can answer some questions I have for the answer of this question:

1. What does "given that" mean?
2. How to slice the sentence up after "given that"?

Comment: Given that => would be something like: `considering the fact that`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in assuming that "given that" is a constituent,  whereas the two words are part of a larger constituent:

*Investors are grateful that the attorney general has stepped in to pursue inquiries into the misfeasance in the financial markets, **given [that the regulators officially charged with policing the industry have been diffident].***

The sequence in bold is a preposition phrase headed by the prep "given", which has the bracketed *that*- clause as its complement, so you have a subordinate clause embedded within a preposition phrase.

The subordinate clause is introduced by the subordinator "that", and has "the regulators officially charged with policing the industry" as subject, and the verb phase "have been difficult" as predicate.

The whole PP functions as a supplementary adjunct whose meaning can be roughly paraphrased as "considering  / in view of / the fact that the regulators ..."

Answer (score 0):

1. As Allan S. Hansen said, it means *considering the fact that* or *since*.

> 2. [...], given that **the regulators officially charged with policing the industry** have been diffident.

The part in bold is the subject of the proposition and the verb is *have been diffident*.

As already said, don't hesitate to go on our [English Language Learners stackexchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) for such questions. We don't bite !

Comment: Ha I didn't notice that English learners have another question site